# What is the best way to change the solution name programmatically in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I'm looking for a way to provide a changing solution/project name functionality to ASP.NET Core Projects. My first idea is to do it programmatically in an installer feature where the developer would write the project name. Is it possible in .NET Framework or via Powershell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below function which will help you in changing:

Here are the reference links:

1) [Link 1](http://dhickey-ie-archive.azurewebsites.net/post/2011/06/03/Rename-a-Visual-Studio-Project-using-PowerShell.aspx)

2) [Link 2](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/batch-updating-changing-visual-studio-projects-with-powershell)

```
function Rename-Project
{
# designed to run from the src folder
param(
    [string]$projectName=$(throw "projectName required."),
    [string]$newProjectName=$(throw "newProjectName required.")
)

if(!(Test-Path $projectName)){
    Write-Error "No project folder '$projectName' found"
    return
}

if(!(Test-Path $projectName\$projectName.csproj)){
    Write-Error "No project '$projectName\$projectName.dll' found"
    return
}

if((Test-Path $newProjectName)){
    Write-Error "Project '$newProjectName' already exists"
    return
}

# project
hg rename $projectName\$projectName.csproj $projectName\$newProjectName.csproj

# folder
hg rename $projectName $newProjectName

# assembly title
$assemblyInfoPath = "$newProjectName\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
(gc $assemblyInfoPath) -replace """$projectName""","""$newProjectName""" | sc $assemblyInfoPath

# root namespace
$projectFile = "$newProjectName\$newProjectName.csproj"
(gc $projectFile) -replace "<RootNamespace>$projectName</RootNamespace>","<RootNamespace>$newProjectName</RootNamespace>" | sc $projectFile

# assembly name
(gc $projectFile) -replace "<AssemblyName>$projectName</AssemblyName>","<AssemblyName>$newProjectName</AssemblyName>" | sc $projectFile

# other project references
gci -Recurse -Include *.csproj |% { (gc $_) -replace "..\\$projectName\\$projectName.csproj", "..\$newProjectName\$newProjectName.csproj" | sc $_ }
gci -Recurse -Include *.csproj |% { (gc $_) -replace "<Name>$projectName</Name>", "<Name>$newProjectName</Name>" | sc $_ }

# solution 
gci -Recurse -Include *.sln |% { (gc $_) -replace "\""$projectName\""", """$newProjectName""" | sc $_ }
gci -Recurse -Include *.sln |% { (gc $_) -replace "\""$projectName\\$projectName.csproj\""", """$newProjectName\$newProjectName.csproj""" | sc $_ }
}
```

Comment: Ranadip Dutta, thank you for your time and consideration in regard to this matter. I'm discussing this solution with my team. It's sound like a good way.